# How to enable part of my vimrc to only apply in gVim?

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I run Vim using both gVim and in terminal.

Basically, I want to enable a certain colorscheme in my vimrc but only when in gVim, as the theme looks terrible in terminal.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if your vim runs in gui:

```
if has("gui_running")
    colo koehler
else
    colo darkblue
endif
```

You can also use `gvimrc` file (`:h gvimrc`) instead.
The drawback is that you would have colorscheme run twice (one in vimrc, another in gvimrc) for gVim unless you guard it in vimrc, again, with `has("gui_running")`:

vimrc

```
if !has("gui_running")
    colo darkblue
endif
```

gvimrc

```
colo koehler
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you.